# Neo4j- incorrect count in multiple match query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

When I am trying to execute this query

```
match(u:User)-[ro:OWNS]->(p:PushDevice) where p.type='gcm' 
match(com:Comment)
return count(com) as total_comments,count(ro) as device
```

this is returning the same number in `both total_comments` and `device` which is the number of total comment.

Comment: Have you tried to do the two matches in separate queries? maybe it's just a  coincidence

Comment: @Supamiu when I am executing separately its working fine. It returns different count.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like your query should work, though I'm more confident that this will work:

```
MATCH (u:User)-[ro:OWNS]->(p:PushDevice) WHERE p.type='gcm' 
WITH count(ro) AS device
MATCH (com:Comment)
RETURN count(com) as total_comments, device
```

Comment: the query you provided is working fine but I've heard that "WITH" is little more time consuming.

Comment: I'd definitely try `PROFILE`ing your queries to see, but I'd guess thatthis would be pretty innocuous since you're just passing along a single number

Answer (score 0):

Your query is generating a row for **every combination** of your `MATCH` results. If you just returned the `ro` and `com` values, this would be more clear. See [this console](http://console.neo4j.org/r/mxzztj) for an example. That console has 2 comments and a single `OWNS` relationship, but the result shows 2 rows (both rows have the same `OWNS` relationship). So, your query is essentially counting the number of rows -- not what you expected.

Here is an example of a query that would work as you you expected:

```
MATCH (u:User)-[ro:OWNS]->(p:PushDevice {type:'gcm'})
WITH COUNT(ro) AS device
MATCH (com:Comment)
RETURN count(com) AS total_comments, device;
```

[EDITED]

This would also work logically, but is less performant (as it takes a cartesian product and then filters out duplicates):

```
MATCH (u:User)-[ro:OWNS]->(p:PushDevice { type: 'gcm' })
MATCH (com:Comment)
RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT com), COUNT(DISTINCT ro);
```

### Observation

The power of neo4j comes from its efficient handling of *relationships*. So, the most efficient queries tend to be for connected subgraphs (where all nodes are connected by relationships).

Since your query is not for a single connected subgraph, getting the answer you want is naturally going to be a bit more convoluted and can be inefficient.

If you determine that the suggested queries are too slow, you can try making 2 separate queries instead. That may also make make your code easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks. 'DISTINCT' is working fine but I have to use multiple match in this query and due to Cartesian product of each node it became huge data and in this case DISTINCT is taking too much time. like in current case total comment is 1023 and device is 22 but it is returning 22506  count in both field so on this amount DISTINCT is taking long time.